# Best approach for selecting products and one of its associated images from 2 mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables. I want to select all products and one of its associated images.

In `images` table, if `default` is true then get that row (4 in this case for 'prod1') .... if 'prod2' doesn't have a default image set, then get first row for `product_id = '2'` (3 in this case)

```
mysql> select * from `products`;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | prod1 |
|  2 | prod2 |
+----+-------+

mysql> select * from `images`;
+----+------------+----------+---------+
| id | product_id | image    | default |
+----+------------+----------+---------+
|  1 |          1 | img1.png |       0 |
|  2 |          1 | img2.png |       0 |
|  3 |          2 | img3.png |       0 |
|  4 |          1 | img4.png |       1 |
|  5 |          2 | img5.png |       0 |
|  6 |          1 | img6.png |       0 |
|  7 |          1 | img7.png |       0 |
|  8 |          2 | img8.png |       0 |
|  9 |          1 | img9.png |       0 |
+----+------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Try doing this:  
Select * from 'products' 
join 'images' 
where 
products.id = images.product_id 
and 
images.default =1
group by product_id LIMIT 1

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu : I get only 1 row for 'prod1' and I need for all products from table....    I have tried this way:  mysql> SELECT p.`name`, i.* FROM `products` p JOIN (SELECT * FROM `images` GROUP BY `product_id` ORDER BY `default` DESC) AS i ON p.`id` = i.`product_id`; ... but I get rows 1 and 3 from `images` because `groupe by` is before `order by` and I need rows 4 and 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the query below to solve your problem:

```
SELECT p.`name`, i.`image`, i.`default`
  FROM products p INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM images i ORDER BY i.`default` DESC) AS temp GROUP BY product_id) i
  ON p.id = i.product_id
```

This will produce the following result:

```
|name  | image    | default
---------------------------
|prod1 | img4.png | 1
|prod2 | img3.png | 0
```

The idea here is to use the byproduct of using GROUP BY which is it always selects the topmost record that it fetches from the certain id. Let's say when you Group By this:

```
|name | image    | default
---------------------------
|blah | img4.png | 1
|blah | img3.png | 0

SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY `name`
```

the result will be:

```
|name | image    | default
---------------------------
|blah | img4.png | 1
```

The real query that answers your question is this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM images i ORDER BY i.`default` DESC) AS temp GROUP BY product_id
```

I sort (descending) the images table by `default` so that the records with the `default` value of 1 is always on top.

I just join it to product table to get the product name as shown in the query above.